# Magento API v1- List prices for all products in one call

Tags: php, magento

I've got the following code:

```
$filters = array('sku' => array('like'=>'%'));
$items = $magConn->call($sessionID, 'product.list', array($filters));
```

This will return an array of all the products and their sku, description, and qty.
However, I also need to get the price?  Is there a way to get that as well?

I've also got this working,

```
$properties = ($magConn->call($sessionID, 'product.info', $item['sku']));
```

which will return all the attributes for one product.  I've got over 2,000 products, and this is definitely not feasible if I want it to end tonight.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way without magento source code modification. You should go to `\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Api.php`, find next lines inside `items()` method:

```
        $result[] = array( // Basic product data
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'name'       => $product->getName(),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
            'category_ids'       => $product->getCategoryIds()
        );
```

and add price here.

Answer (score 0):

Load the collection :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

Get actual price :

```
$product->getPrice();
```

Get special price :

```
$product->getFinalPrice();
```

Comment: of course, you should get `$productId` from your `$items` variable first.

Comment: This isn't using the API.  Not what I needed.