# Magento API - Get Product Names from specific Category

Tags: api, magento, soap, product

I'm working on the Magento API and I got some questions...
I try to get all Product Names from a specific category at Magento.

here's my code for that:

```
<?php
        $host = "www.host.tld/index.php";
        $client = new SoapClient("http://".$host."/api/soap/?wsdl"); 
        $apiuser= "user"; //webservice user login
        $apikey = "pass"; //webservice user pass
        try { 
            // Login
            $sess_id= $client->login($apiuser, $apikey);

        // Getting all products from category
            $filters = array( 'category_ids' => array('107') );
            $productList = $client->call($sess_id, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts', $filters);  
            //iterate and get all the product_id's and put it into one array
            foreach($productList as $products => $values){ 
                    if (isset($values['product_id']) || array_key_exists('product_id', $values)) {
                        $product_ids[] = $values['sku'];
                    }
            }
            //Get product details from product_id
            foreach($product_ids as $key => $values) {
                $details = $client->call( $sess_id, 'product.info', array($values));
                #echo $details['name'];
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception $e) { //while an error has occured
            echo "==> Error: ".$e->getMessage();
               exit();
        }
?>
```

The main problem I have is, that the performance I get is not the best. For each "product name" I make one api-call for getting all products. Every time for each product. That's probably not so clever.

What can I optimize. Am I missing something?

I can imagine, that if I want to get the details from more than one category, my server will crash ;). We have about 1000 products in our shop.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The answer is essentially the same as the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414335/magento-getting-the-details-of-multiple-products-in-a-single-xml-rpc-call/9415112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use to **catalog_category.assignedProducts**

> Retrieve the list of products assigned to a required category.

try this if you are using SOAP V1:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

// If somestuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts', '4');
var_dump($result);

// If you don't need the session anymore
//$client->endSession($session);
```

if you are using SOAP V2:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

$result = $proxy->catalogCategoryAssignedProducts($sessionId, '4');
var_dump($result);
```

and the respond would be like this:

```
array
  0 =>
    array
      'product_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'type' => string 'simple' (length=6)
      'set' => string '4' (length=1)
      'sku' => string 'n2610' (length=5)
      'position' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 =>
    array
      'product_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'type' => string 'simple' (length=6)
      'set' => string '4' (length=1)
      'sku' => string 'b8100' (length=5)
      'position' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: you know how to get all category list using magento rest oauth api?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Products/product_categories.html here's the link. hope it's help

Comment: but if you want add other filter, you can't use CategoryAssignedProducts.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$filters = array(
    'id' => array('in' => array(<product_id_1>, <product_id_2>, ...))
);

$products = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.list', array($filters));
```

If you need some extended info about product - you should alter magento code, see this my answer on the similar questionL [Magento API v1- List prices for all products in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981847/magento-api-v1-list-prices-for-all-products-in-one-call/8984916#8984916)

Comment: This doesn't work but actually I don't need this snippet at all. I figured out, how to get it from multiple categorys. My main problem is the performance.
Example: I do not need the names of the whole stadium ti search a person again and again. Right? I just get the names once and filter in this "array" for the right name, if you know what I mean! :)

Comment: Totally don't understand you now, sorry.

Comment: Haha sorry.
As you see, I first get all the product IDs from one specific category and save it into an array. After that, I iterate over this array to get product specific information. In this case, one product is one api call... imagine that, if you have like 1000 products = 1000 api calls. My server will go down....

Comment: @zyava you know how to get all category list using magento rest oauth api?

Comment: See http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/introduction_to_rest_api#products Product Categories section